# Crtical Points are Global Minima. Does this imply Convexity?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I am a bit confused with the following:

We know if a function is convex then critical points are global minima. Is the converse also true? That is if we know that the set of the critical points are infact the global minima, will it imply that the function is convex?

I am not being able to come up with a counter example in 1 dimension. Nor can I prove it in general. Any help is appreciated.

I mean I guess one can ask what happens if there are no critical points for example say $|x|$ but I guess even in general this is a nice question which sort of asks about even the most basic of concepts

Comment: Your statement "then critical points imply global minima." do you know any konvex function with more than 1 global minimum, so you have a set of critical points and not only one global Minimum

Comment: I sort of edited the question for better understanding. Note I didnt mention strict or strong convexity in any way

Comment: $f(x) = x^2/(1+x^2)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: If this were true, then all functions without critical points would be convex, since these vacuously distill any condition placed on their critical points. That's obviously false.